# Google Charts - Formatting Date in Line Chart Tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In Google Charts, is there a way to change the date formatting of the tooltip value, without making it an HTML tooltip. For example, by default I get this:

[image: tooltip without formatting]

But what I really want is this:

[image: tooltip with formatting]

The chart code is as following:

```
data_table = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graph_data_raw);
chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('DivGraph'));
chart.draw(data_table, {
    hAxis: {
        ticks: x_ticks,
        format: 'MMM d, y',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found the solution, using `DateFormat`:

```
var date_formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ 
    pattern: "MMM dd, yyyy"
}); 
date_formatter.format(data_table, 0);  // Where 0 is the index of the column
```

Comment: In Timeline charts at least, you can further customize tooltips, whether to customize date format or any other need. I am not certain whether it applies to Line, but it may. [See the Timeline docs for exact details, and an example.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#customizing-tooltips)